# Searching for EditText value from Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I previously posted a question about how to search for an edittext's value in firebase and realized how I had my database set up was wrong. Now I have my data formatted like this:

```
{
  "Aaron A" : {
    "allDj" : {
      "-Le5EpHND7KF--XOT7Lc" : "hahahaha",
      "-Le5EsTfNaQ9h3BVeZRw" : "hahahaha",
      "-Le5Fgurpir7bIN3agRb" : "yousucks",
      "-Le5IsCThArSKGRTPnN5" : "ffffggg"
    }
  },
  "allDeeJays" : {
    "-Le5FguoZsnT2lejgAkZ" : "yousucks",
    "-Le5IsCPK69NTbgbgUUo" : "ffffggg",
    "-Le5J5CmPkddSaK_MgpG" : "ahhhaahhaahha"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to search through "allDeeJays", here is what I have so far:

```
query = mProfileDatabase.orderByChild("allDeeJays")
                      .startAt(t.getText().toString()).endAt(t.getText().toString() + "\uf8ff");
```

I can't wrap my head around why this doesn't work, any help plus an explination would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

After replacing what I had with:

```
        query = mProfileDatabase.child("allDeeJays")
                .orderByValue()
                .startAt(t.getText().toString()).endAt(t.getText().toString() + "\uf8ff");
```

I'm getting a new error, logcat does not specify what line it is on:

```
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.android.heydj.DjProfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allDeeJays` node in your JSON doesn't have a string value, so your conditions (like `.startAt(t.getText().toString())`) won't return anything.

You're probably looking for:

```
query = mProfileDatabase.child("allDeeJays")
                  .orderByValue()
                  .startAt(t.getText().toString()).endAt(t.getText().toString() + "\uf8ff");
```

Comment: Now I am getting a new error: (question has been updated accordingly)

Comment: That's a new error, and shows that with the updated code you are getting results. You need to get the value of each child snapshot as a `String`, where you seem to be doing something else. I can't say what that is from what you shared so far, so I'd recommend opening a new question with the minimal code+data that are needed to reproduce this new error.